# MySQL: index a field that contains only distinct values?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Is it useful for SELECT performance to set an index on a field that contains only distinct values?

eg:

```
order_id
--------
98317490
10928343
82931376
93438473
...
```

Comment: Is it a foreign key? Then it is indexed already. It is useful if you use this column to filter you data.

Comment: @juergen d No it's not a foreign key and just saying that it is useful performancewise like the other repliers is just not enough. How do you know? Do you have a source? I will explain both scenarios and post the results.

Comment: but you're right. The explain plan shows full table scan vs. ref type using index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it useful for SELECT performance to set an index on a field that contains only distinct values?

That depends. An index is useful if you often search on this column:

- WHERE column=value
- WHERE column BETWEEN a AND b

The usefulness of an index is determined by its selectivity. For example, if your column contains a boolean, which is:

- false in 99.9% of rows
- true in 0.1% of rows

Then you can easily guess that using an index to find "true" values will be a huge boost relative to reading the entire table to search for them.

On the other hand, searching for "false" using an index will be slower than not using an index, since you're gonna read the whole table anyway, you might as well not bother to also process the index.

If values are all distinct, then selectivity is maximum, and index will be very useful. That is, assuming you actually search on that column!

An index that is never used only slows down updates.

Comment: Explained the SELECT order_id FROM table WHERE order_id = 98317490 without having an index an with having one. It shows full table scan vs. ref type using index. So your answer seems right!

Comment: yeah, the point of having an index is to avoid full table scans so... it works ;)

Comment: But couldn't it be possible that finding the value in the distinct index list and then retrieving the row from the table costs more effort than performing a full table scan?

Comment: Cases where index would be slower... Your table has something like 10 rows in it, a full table scan can be faster... Or stuff like you join the entire table and your DB supports merge/hash joins.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is useful, as with all indexes - it is useful if you have select statements where you have this field on the WHERE clause.

Whether this field has distinct values or not doesn't really matter.

Note that if your field is marked as UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY in the database, the database will technically already have an index for this field, so adding another index for it will not change anything.